# How can I block a https googlead script from running in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I wish to block a script from running in webview but I've not been able to find a solution.

In the head of the html is a single line of code I wish to block -

Please note that the site is https:// and that I do not have the option to simple edit the html code.

Many thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    //run in fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //create a new webview instance and make the current activity as its context
    wb = new WebView(this);

    //show it as our view
    setContentView(wb);

    //enable javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }  

         @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
               if (url.equals("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js")) {

                   ByteArrayInputStream test1 = null;
            try {
                test1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("// script blocked".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                   return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", test1);                                                         


               } else {
                   return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
               }
            }           
    });             

    //load the website 
    wb.loadUrl("https://example.com/");   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use shouldInterceptRequest() to intercept script loading.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
       if (url.equals("script_url_to_block")) {
           return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", new ByteArrayInputStream("// script blocked".getBytes("UTF-8")));
       } else {
           return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I've attempted to add your code but the debugger shows it still returning the code. Clearly I'm a novice so it's my code that's not correct. I've edited and added the code to the OP.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed? Replacce the string "// script blocked" with "alert('script blocked')" to test if the new content is injected in the page.

Comment: I don't think it is. The debugger shows it stepping through the code when it finds the url but it then always executes the else statement returning super. I added the change you suggested and it's not working.

Comment: change url.equals(...) to url.endsWith("adsbygoogle.js")

and add a logging statement

Log.d("WebViewIntercept", "url: " + url);

Comment: wow.. working now.. there was a second script that I didn't catch. Working a treat. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond and come back with such fast replies.